# Does the Rocket Artillery in Civ5 have to set-up prior to firing?

Tags: civilization-5

The civilopedia entry states that the rocket artillery does not need to set-up prior to firing. Yet it seems in my games it needs to, just as any other artillery unit.

Is the civilopedia entry wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this](http://forums.2kgames.com/forums/showpost.php?p=1201610&postcount=5) and [this](http://forums.2kgames.com/forums/showpost.php?p=1201855&postcount=8) answers on the 2k forums, Rocket Artillery *built* in a city does not need to "set up" prior to firing. However, if you upgraded an old unit (artillery) to a R.A. it will still need to "set up" prior to firing.

Comment: I can confirm this. It was very frustrating for me when I discovered upgraded units had to be set up :(

Comment: But you still have an additional movement point, so you can move, set up and fire in the same turn. Also IMO upgraded veteran artillery units are much more valuable, because they ussualy already have Logistics promotion, which allows to fire twice a turn, which is just great.

Comment: But logistics is less useful if you have to setup before each fire.  If you can add logistics to true rocket artillery, then it can move, fire, move, fire, which is even greater.

Comment: @Daniel Lew, rocket artillery doesn't have that many movement points to move twice and fire twice as firing takes a point. And you don't have to set up before each firing, only after movement.